# Replace SELECT INTO Clause with INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

Below is a stored procedure written to search for items in the shop. It was working fine in SQL Server 2008. But when I run this in SQL Azure I found that SELECT INTO is not supported.

I decided to go with `CREATE #Table` and Use `INSERT INTO(Col) Values()`.

The problem is number of columns are dynamic based on search criteria. Example in below procedure is `DISTANCE` column.  This will be returned only if user selects a city.

**How do I use CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO with Dynamic SQL in below procedure?**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchItems]
(
 @ShopId INT
,@unitItems INT = 20
,@sortOrder INT = 0
,@language CHAR(2) = 'EN'
,@catId INT
,@search NVARCHAR(100) = ''
,@cityId INT = 0
,@page INT
,@currentDate DATETIME2(0)
,@currentUserId INT = 0
,@itemType TINYINT = 0
,@unitRows INT OUTPUT
,@unitPages INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@sqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlTempTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'itemSearch'
        ,@sqlInto NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlFrom NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlClause NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@sqlGroup NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
        ,@params NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@sortOrderString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ORDER BY IT.CREATEDATE DESC'


SET @sqlSelect =
    'SELECT     
                 IT.ITEMId
                ,IT.USERId
                ,IT.ShopId
                ,IT.ITEMID
                ,IT.ITEMNAME                    
                ,IT.LASTUPDATED

                ,CY.COUNTRYNAME AS COUNTRYNAME
                ,CI.CITYNAME AS CITY
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @sortOrderString + ') AS RowNumber'

SET @sqlGroup =
    ' GROUP BY  IT.ITEMId
                ,IT.USERId
                ,IT.ShopId
                ,IT.ITEMID
                ,IT.ITEMNAME                    
                ,IT.LASTUPDATED                 
                ,CY.COUNTRYNAME
                ,CI.CITYNAME'

SET @sqlFrom =
    ' FROM      dbo.ITEM AS IT
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Shop AS J
            ON  IT.ShopId = J.ShopId
    INNER JOIN  dbo.CITY AS CI
            ON  CI.CITYID = J.CITYID
    INNER JOIN  dbo.COUNTRY AS CY
            ON  CI.COUNTRYISO = CY.COUNTRYISO
    INNER JOIN  dbo.REGION AS R
            ON  CI.REGIONId = R.REGIONId'

    IF (@cityId > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlFrom = @sqlFrom +
            ' INNER JOIN    dbo.CITY AS CI2
                        ON  CI2.CITYID = @cityId'       
        SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect +
            ',dbo.GetDistance(CI2.LATITUDE) AS DISTANCE '       
        SET @sqlGroup = @sqlGroup +
            ',CI2.LATITUDE'
    END

    SET @sqlInto = ' INTO ' + @sqlTempTable + ' ';      
    SET @sql =  @sqlSelect +
                @sqlInto +
                @sqlFrom +
                @sqlClause +
                @sqlGroup

END
```

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your temp table also need to dynamically created, or else, it is not in same context, it will return your temp table not defined error. Basically you do the following:
Add a parameter like following

```
declare @definetmp varchar(max)
set @definetemp =' declare  @tempTable table ( ItemID int, 
                                              UserID int,
                                              ....
                 '
.....
set @sqlInto = 'Insert into @tempTable' 
......
set @sql = @definetemp +
           @sqlInto + 
           @sqlSelect+
           ....
```

The key point is, your temp table is created also in your dynamic sql.

Comment: declare  @tempTable or declare  #tempTable? Is this SQL Server or Oracle syntax? I am new to sql :)

Comment: declare @temptable is table variable, which is per transaction, transaction end, its life cycle end, it is T-SQL; create #temptable is creating temp table, which is also T-SQL; in your case, you can also create temp table #temp, but it is per session, make sure you drop or truncate when you need.

Comment: Fine sounds good! I need to write some thing like Insert `INTO @temp (Col1,Col2,Col3) SELECT Val1,Val2,Val3` . Correct? I started learning SQL only now, so asking your expertise :)

Comment: Following this article. http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, always good to learn something new, remember you need your table variable in your dynamic sql too. But if you use temp table #tmp, that is different, you can use your dynamic sql refers to it directly. Anyway, just do a little research. Good luck.

Comment: Its working well :) But i load 50000+ Records of 20 columns into table variable. Can i use Temptable or go with Table variable?